# "В стиле" или "в жанре"; в кавычках, или без; заглавными буквами, или строчными?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Альбом включает подборку фантазийных работ в стиле НЮ...
Альбом включает подборку фантазийных работ в стиле "ню"...

Answer (score 1):

А зачем ню кавычить? Стили и жанры не кавычатся.

См. [Фотография в стиле ню](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D1%8E).

**[Ню](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%8E_(%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%80))**

> (фр. nu — сокращённое от фр. nudité — «нагота, обнажённость») —
>   художественный жанр в скульптуре, живописи, фотографии и
>   кинематографе, изображающий красоту и эстетику обнажённого
>   человеческого тела.

[Вопрос № 293572](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20293572)

> Добрый день. Обособляется ли причастный оборот в этом случае:
>   "украшенные бахромой по всей поверхности платья в стиле «латина»".
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Запятые не требуются. Кавычки также не нужны: ...*в стиле латина*.
>
> ---

[Вопрос № 249448](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%20249448)

> Здравствуйте! Хочу разобраться с употреблением слова "хай-тек". Нужно
>   ли брать в кавычки: гостиная в стиле "хай-тек". Корректно ли:
>   "хайтечные" стулья и хай-тек-интерьер. Изменяется ли это слово:
>   четкость линий хай-тек(а). Спасибо!
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> *Хай-тек* – несклоняемое существительное, пишется оно без кавычек. Прилагательное от него в литературном языке не образуется. Корректно:
>   *гостиная в стиле хай-тек, хай-тек-стулья, хай-тек-интерьер, четкость линий хай-тек.*
>
> ---

[Вопрос № 241829](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=241829)

> У меня вопрос о жанрах. В чём отличие фантастики от фэнтези? Если
>   можно, подробно. И второе. Как правильно писать: "фэнтези",
>   "фэнтази", "фентези", "фентази" или как-то ещё?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Правильно: *фэнтези*. Жанр фэнтези основан на сюжетном допущении
>   иррационального характера. Это допущение не имеет логической мотивации
>   в тексте, предполагает существование фактов и явлений, не поддающихся,
>   в отличие от научной фантастики, рациональному объяснению.
>
> В научной фантастике мы имеем дело с единой научно обоснованной
>   посылкой (например, если речь идет о перемещении во времени,
>   обосновывается механизм работы машины времени, если сюжет основан на
>   превращении человека в невидимку, подробно рассказывается об опытах,
>   ведущих к такому результату). В фэнтези же фантастических допущений
>   может быть сколько угодно, в этом особом мире все возможно – боги,
>   демоны, добрые и злые волшебники, говорящие животные и предметы,
>   мифологические и легендарные существа (нимфы, фавны, сатиры, эльфы,
>   гоблины, гномы, хоббиты и пр.), привидения, вампиры и пр. В научной
>   фантастике действие происходит в определенное время и в определенном
>   месте (например, на космической станции в будущем). Миры фэнтези
>   лишены географической и временной конкретности: события происходят в
>   условной реальности, где-то и когда-то, часто в параллельном мире,
>   похожем отчасти на наш.

Comment: Значит, употребленные здесь кавычки - это ошибка? https://ru.euronews.com/2018/07/09/australia-nude-art-photo-shoot "Фантазийный" - от слова "фантазия" (но не фантастика). Американизм "фэнтэзи" - это калька английского слова "fantasy". Слово сходное, но мне не нравится. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/фантазийный. Могу ли я написать НЮ заглавными буквами, или это будет приравнено к ошибке?

Comment: НЮ заглавными буквами - ошибка! Употреблённые здесь, в цитате, кавычки - не ошибка: есть предшествующие ***слово, американизм***, они и обусловили кавычки, не относящиеся с жанру/стилю.